# Unable to write pandas Dataframes to csv, getting IO error

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I have a pandas Df that I am trying to write to csv but unable to. Here is my code:

```
_bytes = c_df.to_csv(None).encode()
with fs.open("s3://bucket/key1/_df.csv", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(_bytes)
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error your code is generating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped me:

```
c_df.to_csv('_df.csv', index=False)  # Preserves the header if present
```

And then uploading separately to s3 using boto3:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file(closed_aoi_filename, s3_bucket, os.path.join(key, closed_aoi_filename))
```

I tried direct solutions to upload pandas df to s3 but wasn't successful. In case anyone has better answers, please let me know. So far this works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using pandas:

```
c_df.to_csv('s3://bucket/key1/_df.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: It says 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'